# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[The first full election](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/3) on Writing has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and your first non-pro-tem moderators are:

[image: Laurel]

[image: linksassin]

[image: F1Krazy]

Please welcome Laurel, who will be joining linksassin and F1Krazy ([the existing crew](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)) shortly — and join with me in thanking and bidding farewell to motosubatsu, who has served the site as a pro-tem mod. Thanks to all of the candidates for volunteering to support this site!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6534571060363264).

Answer (score 10):

I already said something to this effect in the mod chatroom, but I'll say it again publicly: **thank you, motosubatsu, for your service to this community**. It's been a pleasure serving alongside you and linksassin for the past year-and-a-bit, and it will be an honour to continue serving alongside linksassin henceforth.

And to Laurel: **congratulations, and welcome aboard!** I look forward to serving alongside you as well, and I have no doubt that you'll do an excellent job.

Commiserations to aniline, the other losing candidate. I think your relative lack of experience counted against you, but thank you for running anyway, and I hope you'll consider running again in any future elections.

Comment: Thanks mate :) it's been a pleasure working with you and @linksassin and I'm sure the site is in great hands with you and laurel

Answer (score 8):

I'm glad to be here. I'll do my best!

Well said, F1Krazy. I hope we continue to see aniline and motosubatsu as active members here on Writing. And thanks again motosubatsu for your service! In addition, I'd also like to thank everyone who voted in the election.